# Элементы коллекции как параметр метода

Tags: java

У меня есть коллекция с некоторыми значениями типа int. Есть метод который принимает один параметр типа int.

Как я могу выполнить метод для каждого значения из коллекции?

Comment: Вызывать метод в цикле, который по коллекции проходит. Или сделать перегрузку метода, который примет в себя список и внутри уже сделает по нему проход циклом и вызовет метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В языке Java интерфейс [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) наследует интерфейс [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html), поэтому вы можете воспользоваться [циклом For-Each](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html):

```java
Collection<Integer> collection = ...;
for (Integer item : collection) {
    myFavoriteMethod(item);
}
```

Таким образом, метод `myFavoriteMethod()` будет вызван последовательно для каждого элемента из коллекции.